# Retrieve Observable subscribers and make them subscribe to another Observable

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

#### Simply put

Given an existing Observable (which has not completed yet), is there a way to retrieve associated subscribers (functions passed to subscribe) to make them subscribe to another Observable instead?

#### Context

A service in my application helps creating *SeverEvent* connections, returning  a *ConnectableObservable* to proxy connection and allow multicasting using *publish* operator. The service keeps track of existing connections via an internal store :

```js
store: {[key: string]: ConnectionTracker};

// …

interface ConnectionTracker {
    url: string;
    eventSource: EventSource;
    observable: rx.ConnectableObservable<any>;
    subscription: rx.Subscription;
    observer: rx.Observer<any>;
    data?: any; // Arbitrary data
}
```

Upon connection creation, if an associated tracker already exists (identity is made using the connection's endpoint), the service should:

- ok <s>Close existing tracker's *ServerEvent* connection</s>
- ok <s>Open a new *SerevrEvent* connection (hence a new ConnectableObservable)</s>
- Replace existing tracker's Observable with the fresh observable **but make existing subscribers now subscribe to the new Observable instead**

Here is the code part which creates *ConnectionTracker*s

```js
/**
* Create/Update a ServerEvent connection tracker
*/
createTracker<T>(endpoint: string, queryString: string = null): ConnectionTracker
{
    let fullUri = endpoint + (queryString ? `?${queryString}` : '')
        , tracker = this.findTrackerByEndpoint(endpoint) || {
            observable: null,
            fullUri: fullUri,
            eventSource: null,
            observer: null,
            subscription: null
        }
    ;

    // Tracker exists
    if (tracker.observable !== null) {
        // If fullUri hasn't changed, use the tracker as is
        if (tracker.fullUri === fullUri) {
            return tracker;
        }

        // At this point, we know "fullUri" has changed, the tracker's
        // connection should be replaced with a fresh one

// ⇒ TODO
// ⇒ Gather old tracker.observable's subscribers/subscriptions to make
//   them subscribe to the new Observable instead (created down below)

        // Terminate previous connection and clean related resouces
        tracker.observer.complete();
        tracker.eventSource.close();
    }

    tracker.eventSource = new EventSource(<any>fullUri, {withCredentials: true});
    tracker.observable = rx.Observable.create((observer: rx.Observer<T>) => {
            // Executed once
            tracker.eventSource.onmessage = e => observer.next(JSON.parse(e.data));
            tracker.eventSource.onerror = e => observer.error(e);
            // Keep track of the observer
            tracker.observer = observer;
        })
        // Transform Observable into a ConnectableObservable for multicast
        .publish()
    ;

    // Start emitting right away and also keep a reference to 
    // proxy subscription for later disposal
    tracker.subscription = tracker.observable.connect();

    return tracker;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you could use just `switchMap` that returns the "new" Observable. The subscribers will stay as they are but receiving values from this "new" Observable.

Comment: I fear _switchMap_ is not what I am looking for. My intent is to create a drop-in replacement Observable, but recover registered observers from previous Observable. Once ServerEvent connection gets closed, the associated Observable becomes obsolete (no source → no _next()_ call anymore), references to the observable can be dropped. _switchMap_ only builds an Observable chain: the original Observable theorically still be on duty (as far as I understand) but because the related connection is closed no value would be emmited anymore and the new Observable wouldn't have a chance to take over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to do things like moving a subscriber to a different observable then you are just not doing things like intended in RxJS. Any such kind of manipulation is basically hacking.

If you occasionally produce a new observable (e.g. by making a request) and you want some subscriber to always be subscribed to the most recent of them, then here's the solution:

```
  private observables: Subject<Observable<Data>> = new Subject();

  getData(): Observable<Data> {
    return this.observables.pipe(switchAll());
  }

  onMakingNewRequest(newObservable: Observable<Data>) {
    this.observables.push(newObservable);
  }
```

This way you can expose a single observable (via `getData()`) to which the client subscribes, but by pushing to `this.observables` you change the actual source of data that the user sees.

As for closing the connection and similar stuff, your observable (the one created with every request or something) should basically take care of releasing and closing stuff when it's unsubscribed from, then you don't need to do any extra handling, the previous observable will automatically get unsubscribed from the moment you push the new one. Details depend on the actual backend you are contacting.

Comment: Your second sentence sounds like what I am looking for and I feel like the _Subject_ / _switchAll_ combo is precisely what I need. I will dig this in, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to carry Subscribers from one Observable over to another manually you should supply listeners with an Observable that will automatically switch to a different Observable when needed.

You do so by working with a *high order Observable* (an Observable that emits Observables) which always switches to the most recent inner Observable.

#### Basic concept

```js
// a BehaviorSubject is used so that late subscribers also immediately get the most recent inner Observable
const higherOrderObservable = new BehaviorSubject<Observable<any>>(EMPTY);

// pass new Observable to listeners
higherOrderObservable.next(new Observable(..));

// get most recent inner Observable
const currentObservable = higherOrderObservable.pipe(switchMap(obs => obs));
currentObservable.subscribe(valueFromInnerObservable => { .. })
```

#### In your case

For every *endpoint* create a `BehaviorSubject` (*tracker supplier*) that emits the Observable (*tracker*) that should be currently used for that *endpoint*. When a different *tracker* for a given *endpoint* should be used, pass this new Observable to the `BehaviorSubject`. Let your listeners subscribe to the `BehaviorSubject` (*tracker supplier*) that automatically supplies them with the right *tracker*, i.e. switches to the Observable that should currently be use.

A simplified version of your code could look like the one below. The specifics depend on how you're using the function `createTracker` throughout your app.

```js
interface ConnectionTracker {
  fullUri: string;
  tracker$: ConnectableObservable<any>;
}

// Map an endpoint to a tracker supplier.
// This is your higher order Observable as it emits objects that wrap an Observable
store: { [key: string]: BehaviorSubject<ConnectionTracker> };
closeAllTrackers$ = new Subject();

// Creates a new tracker if necessary and returns a ConnectedObservable for that tracker. 
// The ConnectedObservable will always resemble the current tracker.
createTracker<T>(endpoint: string, queryString: string = null): Observable<any> {
  const fullUri = endpoint + (queryString ? `?${queryString}` : '');
  // if no tracker supplier for the endpoint exists, create one
  if (!store[endpoint]) {
    store[endpoint] = new BehaviorSubject<ConnectionTracker>(null);
  }
  const currentTracker = store[endpoint].getValue();

  // if no tracker exists or the current one is obsolete, create a new one
  if (!currentTracker || currentTracker.fullUri !== fullUri) {
    const tracker$ = new Observable<T>(subscriber => {
      const source = new EventSource(fullUri, { withCredentials: true });
      source.onmessage = e => subscriber.next(JSON.parse(e.data));
      source.onerror = e => subscriber.error(e);
      return () => source.close(); // on unsubscribe close the source
    }).pipe(publish()) as ConnectableObservable<any>;
    tracker$.connect();
    // pass the new tracker to the tracker supplier
    store[endpoint].next({ fullUri, tracker$ });
  }
  // return the tracker supplier for the given endpoint that always switches to the current tracker
  return store[endpoint].pipe(
    switchMap(tracker => tracker ? tracker.tracker$ : EMPTY), // switchMap will unsubscribe from the previous tracker and thus close the connection if a new tracker comes in
    takeUntil(this.closeAllTrackers$) // complete the tracker supplier on emit
  );
}

// close all trackers and remove the tracker suppliers
closeAllTrackers() {
  this.closeAllTrackers$.next();
  this.store = {};
}
```

If you want to close all tracker connections at once and existing subscribers should get a `complete` notification, call `closeAllTrackers`.
If you only want to close some tracker connections but don't want existing subscribers ro receive a `complete` notification, so that they keep listening for new trackers supplied in the future, call `store[trackerEndpoint].next(null)` for each tracker.

Comment: What if I need to drop existing connections all at once ? Would looping over _store_  own properties and call _.complete()_ on every BehaviorSubject be enough?

Comment: You probably don't want to complete the BehaviorSubjects themself because you wouldn't be able to emit any new trackers afterwards if you wanted to. Instead just pass `null` to each tracker supplier: `store[endpoint].next(null)`. I edited the last return statement so that if `null` is passed to a BehaviorSubject it will switch to an `EMPTY` observable that just completes. This way you're previous tracker will be unsubscribed from and listeners won't receive any data until a new Observable is passed to the BehaviorSubject.